# How to fund transfer between bank accounts DDD style with EventStore?

Tags: domain-driven-design, eventstoredb

We have an account A and an account B. We want transfer funds/money between A and B. Assume we have an aggregate root for an account. According to Eric Evan's Book we would need a Domain Service to handle the transfer logic. 
For immidiate consistency we would then need to modify account A and account B in a single transaction. Is it possible to write to two different streams (account A and account B) in a single transaction using EventStore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to write to two different streams (account A and account B) in a single transaction using EventStore?

As of V5 RC1 (December 2018), I can't find any evidence that Event Store supports a coordinated write to multiple event streams.

Assuming that your data model is correct, and that two accounts really do belong in different streams: that implies that you don't have a hard transaction boundary to manage, but a process.

Analogy: consider a bank transfer -- do you think we move money from an account at Bank of America to an account at Wells Fargo in a single transaction?

The more usual approach would be to manage the transfer process in a stream of its own, which is keeping track of of everything that has happened.  The changes to the accounts still happen in their own streams, in isolation from one another.  The process stream is responsible for the orchestration -- verifying the acknowledgements from the other elements.

The happy path of the flow might look something like:

1. Record the transfer request in the process stream
2. Record the funds withdrawal in the account A stream
3. Record the *acknowledgement* of the funds withdrawal in the process stream
4. Record the funds deposit in the account B stream
5. Record the *acknowledgement* of the funds deposit in the process stream

   - Record the process completed in the process stream

But if you really need to modify the two accounts *at the same time*, then you need that they are managed by the same [coarse grained lock](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/coarseGrainedLock.html).  Since event store is only guaranteeing locking at the stream level, then you would need to reevaluate your data model.

Comment: that would be a proccess manager or saga pattern, which feels like accedential complexity when the streams are on the same database and will stay there. Its this thin line where single aggregates just can not satisfy some invariants without an another aggregate, but the invariants are not complex enough to justify a long running process implementation. Its a pitty that EventStore does not support this...